# copy an array and keep its column name

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array bars

```
`(datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 27, 0, 0), 2970.0, 3018.0, 2958.0, 3016.0, 4814822.0),
(datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 28, 0, 0), 3035.0, 3115.0, 3026.0, 3115.0, 6604372.0)],
 dtype=[('Timestamp', 'O'), ('open', '<f8'), ('high', '<f8'), ('low', '<f8'), ('close', '<f8'), ('atr', '<f8')])`
```

I want to hard copy it into another array, and change the target array column names:

```
destBars = bars.copy()
destBars.dtype.names=['Timestamp','hl','oh','ol','tr','atr']
bars.dtype.names
('Timestamp', 'hl', 'oh', 'ol', 'tr', 'atr')
```

but after that the bars column changed too. This is not what I expected, I want the `bars.dtype.names` to stay UNCHANGED.

Can someone explain what is wrong, and what I should do?

Comment: You seem to only be doing a shallow copy of the array.

Comment: Looks like the copy is sharing the `dtype` object.  I'd to experiment to see if there's an easy way around that.  `numpy.lib.recfunctions` may have relevant function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `copy`, use `deepcopy` of `copy` module.

Try below code and check

```
import copy
destBars = copy.deepcopy(bars)
```

Comment: I know, right? But try it yourself with the example given, `bars = np.array([(dt.datetime(2017, 4, 27, 0, 0), 2970.0, 3018.0, 2958.0, 3016.0, 4814822.0),
(dt.datetime(2017, 4, 28, 0, 0), 3035.0, 3115.0, 3026.0, 3115.0, 6604372.0)],
 dtype=[('Timestamp', 'O'), ('open', '<f8'), ('high', '<f8'), ('low', '<f8'), ('close', '<f8'), ('atr', '<f8')])`, `destBars = copy.deepcopy(bars)`

Comment: This is an array, not a list.  Deepcopy relies on the array's own copy method.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently a structured array copy makes a copy of the data buffer, but still shares the `dtype` object.  I've never explored this, but I'm not surprised:

```
In [206]: x = np.ones(3, dtype='i,i')
In [207]: x
Out[207]: 
array([(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [208]: id(x.dtype)
Out[208]: 2860363240
In [209]: y = x.copy()
In [210]: id(y.dtype)
Out[210]: 2860363240
```

the object id's match

`x.dtype` does not have a copy method.

Making a new dtype from the `descr` followed by `astype` works:

```
In [5]: x=np.ones(3, 'i,i')
In [6]: dt1=np.dtype(x.dtype.descr)
In [7]: y=x.astype(dt1)
In [8]: y.dtype.names=['a','b']
In [9]: y
Out[9]: 
array([(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<i4')])
In [10]: x
Out[10]: 
array([(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

It seems to be best to changes the names after the `astype`.  Otherwise I get a Futurewarning.

```
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Assignment between structured
arrays with different field names will change in numpy 1.13.

Previously fields in the dst would be set to the value of the
identically-named field in the src. In numpy 1.13 fields will instead 
be assigned 'by position': The Nth field of the dst will be set to the
Nth field of the src array.
```

Comment: `x.dtype` does not have a copy method, but you can use `copy.deepcopy(x.dtype)` to the same effect.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be `deepcopy`. `copy.copy` is enough.  But if you are going to get deeper into manipulating `dtypes`, it's a good idea to become familiar with attributes like the `.descr`.  The `recfunctions` make extensive use of that.

Comment: `np.dtype(dt, copy=True)` takes a `copy` parameter, but that doesn't seem to be working.  I may have to submit a bug/issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want:

```
data.astype([('atr','atr1')])
```